# Dropzone Not Recognising File Or MIME Type Request Header. MVC .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, xmlhttprequest, dropzone.js

I am using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload a file with an `.msg` extension and a MIME type of `application/vnd.ms-outlook`.

When I select a file with a `.msg` extension the file type is empty.

This can be fixed by implementing an `accept` function and setting the file type
however, when the request is sent the MIME type is set to `application/octet-stream` which is the default when the content type
is unknown or empty.

---

**Question**

How can I set the `Content-Type` for the file e.g. *MyFile.msg* in the `multipart/form-data;` to `application/vnd.ms-outlook`?

---

**Request**

```
POST www.someurl.com
...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMagrF5N9EvrTWyiY
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
...

------WebKitFormBoundaryMagrF5N9EvrTAAA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

MyFile.msg
------WebKitFormBoundaryMagrF5N9EvrTAAA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Details"

------WebKitFormBoundaryMagrF5N9EvrTAAA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="MyFile.msg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream //NEED TO CHANGE
```

**Dropzone**

```
accept: function (file, done) {

        // file.type = ""

        if (file.name.split('.').pop()=== 'msg') {
            Object.defineProperty(file, 'type', { value: 'application/vnd.ms-outlook' });
        }           

        done();
    }
},
init: function () {

    this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, data) {
            // This sets the Content-type for the request not just the
            // uploaded file i.e. one boundary of multipart/form-data

            // var send = xhr.send;
            // xhr.send = function () {
            //    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);                  
            //    send.call(xhr, file);
            // };
        }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // file.ContentType is application/octet-stream
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out or get an answer?

Comment: What is the solution for this ?